# Как оценить сложность модели нейронной сети

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, keras, сложность

Есть две модели для классификации изображений кошек и собак.

Могу ли я как-нибудь оценить сложность этих моделей?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import shutil
import os
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array

# Каталог с набором данных
data_dir = 'C:/Users/Mi/Desktop/Machine learning/train_cats_vs_dogs/train/'
# Каталог с данными для обучения
train_dir = 'C:/Users/Mi/Desktop/Machine learning/train_cats_vs_dogs/traini/'
# Каталог с данными для проверки
val_dir = 'C:/Users/Mi/Desktop/Machine learning/train_cats_vs_dogs/val/'
# Каталог с данными для тестирования
test_dir = 'C:/Users/Mi/Desktop/Machine learning/train_cats_vs_dogs/test/'
# Часть набора данных для тестирования
test_data_portion = 0.15
# Часть набора данных для проверки
val_data_portion = 0.15
# Количество элементов данных в одном классе
nb_images = 12500
# Размеры изображения
img_width, img_height = 150, 150
# Размерность тензора на основе изображения для входных данных в нейронную сеть
# backend Tensorflow, channels_last
input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)
# Количество эпох
epochs = 10
# Размер мини-выборки
batch_size = 16
# Количество изображений для обучения
nb_train_samples = 17500
# Количество изображений для проверки
nb_validation_samples = 3750
# Количество изображений для тестирования
nb_test_samples = 3750
# Архитектура модели нейронной сети
import time
# Время работы блока алгоритма
class Profiler(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        self._startTime = time.time()

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        print("Elapsed time: {:.3f} sec".format(time.time() - self._startTime))

# Сверточная нейронная сеть
with Profiler() as p:
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(64))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
    train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='binary')
    val_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        val_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='binary')
    test_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        test_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='binary')
    model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
        epochs=epochs,
        validation_data=val_generator,
        validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)
# Проверка модели на тестовых данных
    scores = model.evaluate_generator(test_generator, nb_test_samples // batch_size)
    print("Точность на тестовых данных: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))

# Полносвязная нейронная сеть
with Profiler() as p:
    model1 = Sequential()
    model1.add(Flatten(input_shape=input_shape))
    model1.add(Dense(32))
    model1.add(Activation('relu')) 
    model1.add(Dense(32))
    model1.add(Activation('relu')) 
    model1.add(Dense(64))
    model1.add(Activation('relu')) 
    model1.add(Dense(64))
    model1.add(Activation('relu')) 
    model1.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model1.add(Dense(1))
    model1.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
    model1.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='sgd',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
    train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='binary')
    val_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        val_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='binary')
    test_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        test_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='binary')
    model1.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
        epochs=epochs,
        validation_data=val_generator,
        validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)
    scores = model1.evaluate_generator(test_generator, nb_test_samples // batch_size)
    print("Точность на тестовых данных: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))
# Тестирование модели на картинке пользователя
classes=['dog','cat']
img = load_img('z.jpg', target_size=(150, 150))
# Преобразование картинки в вектор
x =img_to_array(img)
x = x.reshape(1,150,150,3).astype('float')
x /= 255
# Применение к вектору сверточной нейронной сети
with Profiler() as p:
    pred = model.predict(x)
    pred = np.around(pred)
    print(classes[int(pred[0][0])])
# Применение к вектору полносвязной нейронной сети
with Profiler() as p:
    pred1=model1.predict(x)
    pred1 = np.around(pred1)
    print(classes[int(pred1[0][0])])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При обучении нейронных сетей расчитываются матрицы весов нейронных связей. Соответственно, одним из самых распространенных способом оценки сложности архитектуры является число параметров, для которых подбираются веса.

Для этого существует метод [model.summary](https://keras.io/models/about-keras-models/):

```
In [4]: model.summary()
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 148, 148, 32)      896
_________________________________________________________________
activation (Activation)      (None, 148, 148, 32)      0
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 74, 74, 32)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 72, 72, 32)        9248
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 72, 72, 32)        0
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 36, 36, 32)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 34, 34, 64)        18496
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 34, 34, 64)        0
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 17, 17, 64)        0
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 18496)             0
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 64)                1183808
_________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)    (None, 64)                0
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 64)                0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 65
_________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)    (None, 1)                 0
=================================================================
Total params: 1,212,513
Trainable params: 1,212,513   # <------ NOTE !!!
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Для второй модели:

```
In [6]: model1.summary()
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 67500)             0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 32)                2160032
_________________________________________________________________
activation_5 (Activation)    (None, 32)                0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 32)                1056
_________________________________________________________________
activation_6 (Activation)    (None, 32)                0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 64)                2112
_________________________________________________________________
activation_7 (Activation)    (None, 64)                0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 64)                4160
_________________________________________________________________
activation_8 (Activation)    (None, 64)                0
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 64)                0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 65
_________________________________________________________________
activation_9 (Activation)    (None, 1)                 0
=================================================================
Total params: 2,167,425
Trainable params: 2,167,425   # <------ NOTE !!!
Non-trainable params: 0
```

**NOTE:** скорость обучения также зависит от функций активации, поэтому такое сравнение будет неточным.

---

С точки зрения оценки **времени** обучения, полезнее / точнее будет попытаться обучить НС на небольшом числе эпох - 3-5 эпох, посчитать среднее время обучения одной эпохи и умножить на число эпох, которые вы планируете использовать для обучения.